# DLookup returning Empty (MS Access 2013)

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am using (or trying to use) DLookUp on a form to auto-populate an address field based on the ID selected, but the address field just stays blank.

Here is the expression I am using

```
=DLookUp("[Address1]","Contacts","[ContactID]= '" & [Forms]![ConveyanceEntry]![FromID] & "'")
```

FromID is on my ConveyanceEntry form, and appears as a dropdown.  The dropdown is tied to the FromID field in my Conveyances table; it gets its values via a lookup:  SELECT [Contacts].[ID], Contacts.[ContactID] FROM Contacts ORDER BY [ContactID];

Is it because the FromID in the Record Source of the form is a lookup field?  It seems like that shouldn't matter.  I checked all my spellings and the Name, Datasheet Caption, and Control Source properties are set to Address1, ContactID, and FromID respectively.  If I replace " & [Forms]![ConveyanceEntry]![FromID] & " with a value it works fine.  Values of the ContactID field can contain letters and numbers.
I am using Access 2013, and now have the accbd available to share if necessary.

Comment: You have added a space at the beginning and the end --  = ' " & [Forms]! This should be  `= '" & [Forms]!`, similarly the end.

Comment: @Fionnuala 
Like this?
`=DLookUp("[Address1]","Contacts","[ContactID]= '" & [Forms]![ConveyanceEntry]![FromID] & "'")`

Comment: Only if `[ContactID]` is text, otherwise `=DLookUp("[Address1]","Contacts","[ContactID]=" & [Forms]![ConveyanceEntry]![FromID])` You do not need to quote numbers.

Comment: @Fionnuala Thank you for the responses.  But without quotes I get "#Error", changing the spaces did not fix the problem either, still showing blank (I double checked, and the FromID I am testing with has a value for Address1).

Comment: What do you get when you type into the immediate window, say: ?DLookUp("[Address1]","Contacts","[ContactID]= '" & [Forms]![ConveyanceEntry]![FromID] & "'") -- Make sure ConveyanceEntry is open.

Comment: If that does not work, substitute a real value, say `?DLookUp("[Address1]","Contacts","[ContactID]='abc'")`

Comment: If I substitute a value for the condition then a proper value is returned.  as for the immediate window, it says taht it cannot find "FromID"; but I think that is because I am using this expression in the "Control Source" property of the text box on the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65993/discussion-between-fionnuala-and-user1754510).

Comment: When I enter `?DLookUp("[Address1]","Contacts","[ContactID]= '" & [Forms]![ConveyanceEntry]![FromID] & "'")` in the Immediate Window now (open ConveyancesEntry --> Select a value for FromID  -->  Control+G --> (Form_ConveyanceEntry shows in the Project Explorer tree) I get Null.

Comment: Solution (Thank you @Fionnuala):

"The main difficulty is that you have two Ids and the bound column of the combo returns Id, not ContactId, this is because you have a row source SELECT Id, Contactid ... a bound column 1, and Column widths 0, 2"

`=DLookUp("[Address1]","Contacts","[ID]= " & [Forms]![ConveyanceEntry]![FromID])`